# VBA Object variable not set while working with Selection and Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range, selection

I'm trying to split lines that contain some value in Excel VBA. The problem is not in splitting and copying rows (I'm not there yet!), but in method 'Application.Intersect'. I think I am passing 2 Ranges but the program crashes with the error "Object variable or with block variable not set".
When I print them I see something like "$A$2 $C$D false" depending on wath I have selected...
What am I doing wrong?

I have this code,

```
Sub SplitRows()
Dim LastRow As Long, _
WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet, _
i As Long, j As Integer, ii As Long, X, Y, _
MySelection As Range

Set WS1 = Sheets("Foglio1")
Set WS2 = Sheets("Foglio2")
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With WS1
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Columns.Count)).Copy
End With

With WS2
    .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

For i = 2 To LastRow
    Dim A As Range, SplitSize As Long

    For ii = 1 To Columns.Count
        Set A = WS1.Cells(i, ii)
        Set MySelection = Selection
        MsgBox A.Address & " " & MySelection.Address & " " & (Application Is Nothing)

        If Not (Application.Intersect(A, MySelection)) Is Nothing Then
            SplitSize = UBound(Split(WS1.Cells(i, ii).Value, ","))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ii
MsgBox "SplitSize is" & SplitSize    
Next i

End Sub
```

**Solution Here**
Just replace this

```
If Not (Application.Intersect(A, MySelection)) Is Nothing Then
```

with that

```
If Not (Application.Intersect(A, MySelection) Is Nothing) Then
```

Comment: Can you check this line, Set MySelection = Selection. As you have used, Application.CutCopyMode = False earlier in the code, there is no active selection available for assigning it to MySelection. Can you check this?

Comment: Just Checked after your comment....Unfortunately, even without 'Application.CutCopyMode = False' the result is the same...

Comment: Is Selection is selecting range from which worksheet? If it is sheet1 then try WS1.Activate before MySelection = Selection

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code to see exactly which line raises the error?

Comment: The line is If Not (Application.Intersect(A, MySelection)) Is Nothing Then

Comment: @Paresh I tried to add the line you suggested but nothing changed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign an object to the intersect first before check if it's nothing:

```
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(A, MySelection)
    If Not isect Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Thank to your comment, I found the problem! I just moved a parens and now it is working

Comment: @Andrea glad that you found the solution!